# How to insert named register from vim commandline

Tags: vim

Using `vim` I have some troubles inserting the value of a specific register using commandline mode.

When in `normal` mode I can enter the sequence `"*p` which will put the value of register `"*` beneath the current line.

If I try to enter the command `"*put` on the commandline nothing happens. On the other hand, if I just issue the `put` command the value of the unnamed register is put.

So the question is, how can I put the content of a named register using commandline mode?

**EDIT #1**

After some additional testing I have found a workaround:

Catch the paste register in a sequence first using `qz1"cpq` where

```
qz  -> start recording into register z
1   -> goto line 1
"cp -> put content of register c
q   -> end recording
```

Using `:@z` the macro can run to perform the required steps. When used in combination with `bufdo`:

```
:bufdo execute "normal @z"
```

The register can be added as a new line into all opened buffers.

While this is a working method I believe there is a more efficient way to perform the same without the need of a macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with command line version of `put`:

```
:put z
```

The full syntax is `:[line]pu[t] [x]`.  Please see `:help :put` for more information.

On a side note: Vim geeks' den is [this way](http://vi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I was searching for and reading all I could find on `:help put` but did not think of `:help :put`

Comment: One tip that may be helpful in the future is, when you type a :help command (or part of one), you can press Ctrl-D to see a listing of the possible completions.  Typing `:help put` and then typing Ctrl-D shows `:put` along with many other related options.